# Any praise of shred-paramis by the Sublime Budddha?

Tags: abhidhamma, right-view, sila, parami

What does one know or think: Is there any praise of shred-parami (perfections in appearing modest) by the Sublime Buddha, such as in out-fit, outwardly appearing, using of such stuff, and if why? If not why?

To give an idea in a samples of certain "modesty":

- Better to catch fishes with the hand instead of catching with high tech, yet still after meat.
- Better to wear recycling garments then new, yet still after look.
- Better to drive an old car then a new one, yet still after comfort.
- Better not to cut hair and let it grow, yet still after appearing certain.
- Spreading "I am content with an old camry" to sign out modesty and swifting to rave as soon conditions make it possible.

*[note: not given for trade, exchange, stacks but for gaining release from the wheel of hypocrisy and corruption]*

Comment: Is the perfection in appearing modest nekkhamma(renunciation)?

Comment: Sometimes, sometimes the opposite, good @Lowbrow.

Comment: I don't know what "shred" means? And  what "appearing certain" means? And "rave" (I don't know about makes of car, but did you mean "RAV4" compared to "Camry")?

Comment: The [wolf's-Uposatha](https://forum.sangham.net/index.php?topic=888.msg2987#msg2987).

Answer (score -1):

How long do $500 shoes last? Do they make you look smart or stupid for buying them? Clothing is a communication. People dress to their personal desires and look for those in the people they put around them. So if you dress a certain way you project. People who want a friend or sucker or someone to complement them in some way. That's the issue of clothing. You are your environment and the people you surround yourself with. I dress like a regular person on the poor side. I have honestly and Carring and supporting friendships that have an intimate understanding of each other. Before I was a Buddhist I was flamboyant and attracted drama and suffering. Cause and affect are the same you see. Clothes make the man but the man picks the cloths. Find the middle way.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99203/discussion-on-answer-by-robert-vanderwolk-any-praise-of-shred-paramis-by-the-sub).

Answer (score -1):

Honored Buddhaparisada, Interested,

In relation of modesty, high ascetic practice, th Sublime Buddha counted four modest af ascetic in regard of the four conditions (food, clother, dwelling, medicine), found in the Suttas as well as in the Abhidhamma-Pitaka:

There are four kind of ascetism:

"The fools" who harms himself thinking it's needed to or does not know how to stay comfortable.

"The accumulator", who uses this mode for his honour to gain worldy means.

"The faithful", who follows the praised asceticism by the Buddha in truth that it is useful for the training.

"The complete", who actually does not have desires and lives material modesty without harming himself or others naturally.

Really a good collection to often reflect on, when taking on modesty, to check whether stupidy, defilements, good faith or wisdom is the drive for it behind. Requires good prove and self-honesty of course.

The first two modes accumulate paramis (perfection) toward low realm and hell, while the second two accumulate perfection and foundation for the path and go beyond, if things are right comprehend.

*(Note: this is not given for trade, exchange, stacks and what binds here in this wheel but for escape from it)*

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the Buddha praised modesty (in terms of not accumulating things) in the [AN 8.53](https://suttacentral.net/an8.53/en/sujato) in the **bolded** lines below. I think it refers to accumulating things and not accumulating evil kamma.

> You might know that certain things
>   *Ye kho tvaṃ, gotami, dhamme jāneyyāsi:*
>
> lead to dispassion, not passion;
>   *‘ime dhammā virāgāya saṃvattanti, no sarāgāya;*
>
> to being unfettered, not to being fettered;
>   *visaṃyogāya saṃvattanti, no saṃyogāya;*
>
> **to dispersal, not accumulation;**
>   *apacayāya saṃvattanti, no ācayāya;*
>
> **to fewer desires, not more;**
>   *appicchatāya saṃvattanti, no mahicchatāya;*
>
> **to contentment, not lack of contentment;**
>   *santuṭṭhiyā saṃvattanti, no asantuṭṭhiyā;*
>
> to seclusion, not crowding;
>   *pavivekāya saṃvattanti, no saṅgaṇikāya;*
>
> to energy, not laziness;
>   *vīriyārambhāya saṃvattanti, no kosajjāya;*
>
> to being easy to look after, not being hard to look after.
>   *subharatāya saṃvattanti, no dubbharatāyā’ti,*
>
> You should definitely bear in mind that these things are
>   *ekaṃsena, gotami, dhāreyyāsi:*
>
> the teaching, the training, and the Teacher’s instructions.”
>   *‘eso dhammo, eso vinayo, etaṃ satthusāsanan’”ti.*

Comment: The question wasn't about modesty general, but certain kind of outwardly appearing like modest, good householder.

Answer (score -1):

**perfections in appearing modest ... such as in outfit, outwardly appearing**

I don't know about the Abhidhamma but the Buddha didn't seem to praise what's modest only in appearance, for example in the Dhammapada,

> `141.` Neither going about naked, nor matted locks, nor filth, nor fasting, nor lying on the ground, nor smearing oneself with ashes and dust, nor sitting on the heels (in penance) can purify a mortal who has not overcome doubt.
>
> `142.` Even though he be well-attired, yet if he is poised, calm, controlled and established in the holy life, having set aside violence towards all beings — he, truly, is a holy man, a renunciate, a monk.
>
> `394.` What is the use of your matted hair, O witless man? What of your garment of antelope's hide? Within you is the tangle (of passion); only outwardly do you cleanse yourself.

**If not why?**

I think you said why in the question -- i.e. "yet still after" -- I think that sounds like craving.